# Detect if string is a quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect when a string is a quote of some kind. For my use case a string can be classed as a quote if it starts with a quotation mark, which will enable me to mark the string as a quote whilst it is being typed out.

#### Test cases

✅ `"I am a quote`
✅ `'I am a quote`
✅ `“I am a quote`
✅  `“I am a quote` 
❌ `I am not a quote`
❌ `This isn't a quote`

Comment: I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution here is quite simple and checks for strings starting with `“"'`:

```js
const getInputTextType = (inputText: string) =>
  /^[“"']/.test(inputText.trim()) ? "quote" : "text";

console.log(getInputTextType('"I am a quote"'));
console.log(getInputTextType("'I am a quote"));
console.log(getInputTextType("“I am a quote"));
console.log(getInputTextType("  “I am a quote  "));
console.log(getInputTextType("I am not a quote"));
console.log(getInputTextType("This isn't a quote"));
```

If anyone knows of any instances where a potential quote wouldn't be caught (based on starting with a quotation mark) let me know.

Comment: Won't work with `getInputTextType("This isn't a quote")`

Comment: good point @adiga, I woke up too early this morning and forgot to make sure the regex only checked the first character, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing to check is the first character, then just compare that first character with `includes` against the string of possible quote characters:

```js
const getInputTextType = (inputText) =>
  `“"'`.includes(inputText.trim()[0]) ? "quote" : "text";

console.log(getInputTextType('"I am a quote"'));
console.log(getInputTextType("'I am a quote"));
console.log(getInputTextType("“I am a quote"));
console.log(getInputTextType("  “I am a quote  "));
console.log(getInputTextType("I am not a quote"));
console.log(getInputTextType("This isn't a quote"));
```

Comment: this seems a decent option, what benefits do you see over my regex solution? potentially slightly easier to read, though it just moves the complexity from having a regex to comparing to one character.

Comment: A regex invokes a regex "engine" that compiles it. It is a very nice tool for detecting patterns. But as this is a single character check, `includes` can be expected to run faster. But this is not important unless this function is called millions of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement in multiple ways.

1. With the help of [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method along with [`String.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const blacklist = ['"', '\'', "“"];

const str = '"I am a quote';

blacklist.every(c => {
  if(str.trim().startsWith(c)) {
    console.log('I am a quote');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})
```

2. By using `RegEx`

Live Demo **:**

```js
const startWithQuoteRegEx = /^[“"']/;

const str = '"I am a quote';

startWithQuoteRegEx.test(str) ? console.log('I am a quote') : console.log('I am not a quote')
```